# List all the columns used in Group by and Order by Clause

Tags: sql, python-3.x, teradata, ksh

I am trying to list out all the columns used in Group by and Order by clause of an sql statement. Is there a way to find that out from the database metadata itself ? If not what is the best possible way to go about this problem.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: What would be wrong with just looking at the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses of the query itself?

Comment: :) . I am trying to write a set up which would store this information in a table or file with respect. Sort of a customised metadata for your application maintenance purpose.

Comment: So you want a script which can parse a SQL query and extract this information, or something else?

Comment: yes. Something of that sort.

Comment: This isn't something that is stored. You are writing these SQL queries, so why not just document what you are using when you submit them. You can also grab querytext from DBC tables, but you are still on the hook to write a SQL parsing script to get what you want from it.

Comment: Peraps start with something like `readsql; statistics` as two functions. The first can read a multiline sql statement from file or stdin. The second can do some sort of parsing and store the interesting data in a file: `sed -n 's/.*ORDER BY//p' .>> logfile`, When this is a good direction, add better parsing in your function.